# ASP.NET exclude property when updating record - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to update banner without changing `AuthorId`, and my DTO does not include `AuthorId` so that field got null value when I submit.

I have followed this post [Exclude Property on Update in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661881/exclude-)

My code:

```
public void UpdateBanner(Banner banner)
{
    _context.Entry(banner).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.Entry(banner).Property(x => x.AuthorId).IsModified = false;

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

            foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        throw;
    }         
}
```

And I get this error:

> The AuthorId field is required.

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory.

**The AuthorId field is required.** It seems to me by looking at the link that you posted as reference, you are still using your primary key field to mark it as `false` for Modified attribute whereas in the link, a field which was not a primary key was used.

So you might want to check that difference in the fields and if its a primary key, then it will demand a value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tthanks for answer me, the AuthorId (not a primary key) was added, but what i want is keeping the old value. So i dont want to include AuthorId in bannerDTO (object to submit when update), that's why AuthorId is null.

Comment: @Kaeszt - Check the DB for this field, if its marked as `not null`.

Comment: I know it it required, but my need is to keep the current value of it, not to update new.

Comment: Then in that case, you will have to pass it as it is. Because a required field will always expect a value, even if its the same value.

Comment: thanks for help, but i still need a better solution, becoz this will +1 query to get the authorId, and the logic is not really updating

Comment: Isn't it received in the `banner` object ?

Comment: yes, it's received for sure, my edit view allow to edit on some specified field, so i pass that fields by a bannerDTO, and the other fields of banner model are null, which i want to keep the old value of

Comment: Well then you might as well pass `AuthorId` to that view and that would solve this. Since its a required field, it would have to maintained during DB transactions.

Comment: Let me explain: 
- 2 reasons why authorId not inlcuded in bannerDTO: 
   + 1st i want to keep old value
   + 2nd - i dont want to show authorId on view
- i dont want to query the current authorId value (performance purpose), so if i must pass it, i still set it as null

Comment: 2 things here. First, if you dont want to show, you can make use of a Hidden Field and have access to the value. Second, check once in the `Banner` model and your EF model, if you have the Required attribute anywhere.

Comment: seem like you don't get my question, thanks for helping