# Retaining a column value on update in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Entity Framework code-first model where each entity implements the following interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    DateTime DateTimeModified { get; set; }
}
```

In the `DbContext`, I have overridden the `SaveChanges` method that does the following:

```
public override int SaveChanges ()
{
    PropertyInfo property = null;
    var interfaceName = typeof(IEntity<>).Name;

    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var type = entry.Entity.GetType();
        var @interface = type.GetInterface(interfaceName, false);

        if (@interface != null)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                property = type.GetProperty("DateTimeCreated");
                property.SetValue(entry.Entity, now);
                property = type.GetProperty("DateTimeModified");
                property.SetValue(entry.Entity, now);
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                // The property [DateTimeCreated] gets reset to default(DateTime).
                property = type.GetProperty("DateTimeModified");
                property.SetValue(entry.Entity, now);
            }
        }
    }

    return (base.SaveChanges());
}
```

The problem lies with the condition `else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)`.

The presentation layer uses `ViewModel` DTOs and there is heavy use of custom code generation in the solution. As a result, using tools like `AutoMapper` and propagating the `IEntity` interface values to and from the DTO is not ideal.

When an entity is updated, and since the DTO knows nothing about the above properties, the `IEntity` instance has its `DateTimeCreated` property set to `default(DateTime)`.

The `IEntity` interface is designed to shield developers/consumers from having to write plumbing code and since we don't propagate the DTOs, the only other option seems to be to make another round-trip to the database to fetch the `DateTimeCreated` value and then call `base.SaveChanges`.

Is there a work-around to avoid this round-trip that I may be missing?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661881/exclude-property-on-update-in-entity-framework

Comment: @kiziu: I did not know you could instruct EF to exclude selective columns. Worked like a charm. Thanks!