# Attribute for "Property not updateble"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application (webservice), where numerous objects are inserted into a database or updated (with `Entity Framework`), but never read. So I even don't have read-access to this database.
Now a new requirement wants some properties to be inserted but never to be updated. I save all objects like this:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
db.Set<TT>().AddOrUpdate(MapObject<TT>(obj)); //Maps to database entity and saves object
```

Now the question is, if there is an attribute I can tell a property to be inserted, but ignored while updating? In best case something like this:

```
[InsertOnly]
public string SomeText { get; set; }
```

Comment: There is no such attribute (feature) in EF. Also note that in order to detect the correct operation (`INSERT` or `UPDATE`), `AddOrUpdate` method *does read* from database, so *"I even don't have read-access to this database"* statement makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `unit of work` save routine, check `ChangeTracker` and remove those records or properties that are marked as update. Something like this:

```
var modifiedItems = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .ToList();
```

`EntityState` has following types:

- Detached
- Unchanged
- Added
- Deleted
- Modified

Comment: As far as I see in MSDN, `DbSet` has a method named `Add` for just adding. And there is not `AddOrUpdate` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx So calling just `Add` method is a safe way too.

Comment: `ChangeTracker` also can be used to find out state of properties too, if it can help.

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661881/exclude-property-on-update-in-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks a lot! Learned something new and pointed me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom attribute.

```
public class InsertOnly : Attribute
{}
```

If we consider

on your EF object, you add the custom property as such:

```
public class SomeEFClass {
       [InsertOnly]
       public int Id {get;set;}
   }
```

Then change

```
db.Set<TT>().AddOrUpdate(MapObject<TT>(obj)); //Maps to database entity and
```

To include something like (This is pseudo code, don't expect it to run)

```
foreach(Property info pi in t.GetProperties())
{
    if(pi.GetCustomAttribute<InsertOnly>() == null)
    {
        //You can safely update this property
    }
    else
    {
        //This property is only for inserting
    }
}
```

I am uncertain if you can add the custom attribute via partial class overloading of a property? That might be worth a shot?