# how to tell Entity Framework to ignore database generates values for insert or update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to `Entity Framework` in `C#`.

I'm having one computational column in my table `table1`(example). I will calculate the computational column value based on the other columns value. I don't want `Entity Framework` to include the computational column while performing insert/update operations. How can I make the `EF` to avoid that particular column. But I want to set the value for that particular column manually.

I searched for the same but i couldn't able to get the answer for my question. Kindly help me  and thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661881/exclude-property-on-update-in-entity-framework

Comment: is the computation database side or "c# code" side ?

Comment: I will calculate the value in database side

Comment: oh ok thanks. will try this and update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`NotMapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#NotMapped) Annotation

> Code first convention dictates that every property that is of a
>   supported data type is represented in the database. That property can
>   be created dynamically and does not need to be stored. You can mark
>   any properties that do not map to the database with the NotMapped
>   annotation.

```
[NotMapped]
public string Something
{
    get
    {
        return _something;
    }
    set
    {
        _something = value
    }
}
```

**Update** : this is will not map to the dB, so is probably not what you are looking for

---

Just to make this a more complete the [`DatabaseGenerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption?view=netframework-4.7.1) Annotation, are the droids you are looking for

> An important database features is the ability to have computed
>   properties. If you're mapping your Code First classes to tables that
>   contain computed columns, you don't want Entity Framework to try to
>   update those columns. But you do want EF to return those values from
>   the database after you've inserted or updated data. You can use the
>   DatabaseGenerated annotation to flag those properties in your class
>   along with the Computed enum. Other enums are None and Identity.

Which can be used with the [`DatabaseGeneratedOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption?view=netframework-4.7.1)

> - **Computed** : The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated.
> - **Identity** : The database generates a value when a row is inserted.
> - **None** : The database does not generate values.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]
public string Something { get; set; }
```

Comment: notmapped will not create that particular column in the database. But, I'm setting the computational column value from DB side. will it be affect?

Comment: @gopip You won't be able to pass it back to the client though

Comment: @GopiP a more complete answer for you

Answer (score 1):

As you calculate your column server side the correct way is to configure the field at the context level with:

- [HasComputedColumnSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns) for ef-core
- [DatabaseGeneratedAttibute](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1) for EF-6 (HasDatabaseGeneratedOption for the fluent api)

If you use `NotMapped`, **you will not get** the value from the database.

Comment: i see that using HasComputedColumnSql updates all rows whenever an update happens for a particular row in DB ? Is it correct behavior  OR am I missing something !