# Ignore JsonPatch specific property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, json-patch

I am currently trying to figure out how I could prevent the user of my API to change/update a specific property. From what I was able to gather from the web was that it is simply not supported, at least by the Microsoft implementation `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch`. Other than that I was able to find the `IObjectAdapter` interface which would allow me to add some custom logic in the `ApplyTo` method. However that seems like a pretty ugly approach.

Obviously I could also use GraphQL, however that would be somewhat overkill for those few times I really need it. Would there be any alternative?

Comment: So your purpose is to update only some fields when updating model in the api? If so, you can limit the `IsModified` attribute to some special fields when updating, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570001/12884742

Comment: @YongqingYu That would work, however I am not using EF Core. Therefor that really won't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around on GitHub I was able to found a gem called [`JsonPath.Patchable`](https://github.com/Labradoratory/JsonPatch.Patchable) by `Labradoratory` which exactly fixes the issue I am having. Although it does break the DDD pattern which doesn't really makes me to happy, but is pretty much the best we can get to.

### Update

I just created a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPatch.Restrict) package, which solves this problem, by providing extension methods which allow you to pass in specific properties which are allowed to be changed.
Example:

```cs
public class DummyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
patchDocument.Replace("/Value", "newValue");

patchDocument.ApplyToWithRestrictions(dummy, "Value"); // Allows the Patch to only modify the Value property. This argument takes an array.
```

The source code to this package is available [here](https://github.com/TwentyFourMinutes/JsonPatch.Restrict).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try restriction by specifying the class serialization,
for example

```
public class UpdatableDummyModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and your input is

```
JsonPatchDocument<UpdatableDummyModel>
```

Comment: That would require me to parse it to a "updateable model" first and then convert it back to the real type. That's also a bit of an ugly work around IMHO.