# db.Entry vs db.update in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, sql-update

I am learning how to create a Web API in .NET Core and I realized that there's another way to update an entry...

I usually update an entry using:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.update(pais);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return new CreatedAtRouteResult("GetById", new { id = pais.Id }, pais);
}
```

But watching a video I realized that he used:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(pais).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return new CreatedAtRouteResult("GetById", new { id = pais.Id }, pais);
}
```

Both work for me, but what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- DbContext update: For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added state. This helps ensure new entities will be inserted, while existing entities will be updated. An entity is considered to have its primary key value set if the primary key property is set to anything other than the CLR default for the property type.
- DbContext Entry: For entity types without generated keys, the state set is always Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified. Use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry.State to set the  state of only a single entity.

I summarize it in the description of the `DbContext update` interface. Hope to help you

Comment: In your case, It is the same